# Logo in Illustrator to Photoshop for High-PPI Export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, export, print-production, ppi

I've created a logo in Adobe Illustrator at the exact dimensions in inches that I want the final result to have (to print on a t shirt). I'd now like to take this logo into Photoshop for post-processing, then finally export it to a png at 300 ppi. The world of resolutions is new to me, however, and I want to make sure I get it right. If I export an image directly from Illustrator at 300 ppi, the image is far bigger than it should be when I open it in Photoshop. If I export from Illustrator at screen resolution (72 ppi), it opens at the correct size in Photoshop, and I know I can change the Photoshop document's resolution to 300 ppi afterwards while maintaining the correct dimensions, but I'm not sure if initially importing a 72 ppi image will result in a loss of quality. I'm hoping someone with some experience in this area would be able to enlighten me on what I should be doing at the following steps:

1. Exporting the initial image from Illustrator
2. Importing the initial image into Photoshop
3. Exporting the final image from Photoshop

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **open** the AI file with Photoshop. The image will by default, open as a smart object.

As a smart object, you can alter/adjust the PPI or size of the Photoshop document and the smart object will **always** reference the original vector artwork. There will be **zero** quality loss in the smart object.

There is generally no need to "export" from Illustrator unless you wish to retain layers and allow rasterization in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

I export from Illustrator to several different specs, one of which is png and jpg at 144ppi for one developer. You can do this all in Illustrator.

From in your Illustrator document:

File > Export > Export As... check "Use Artboards" and select your range or all. Select Export and you'll get the png options window, which allows you to select a predetermined resolution or input your own. Select your anti-aliasing option, background (default is transparent) and click OK.

Your png file will show and send with the correct ppi.